# How to use OrderBy extension method with a collection of dynamic objects?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dynamic, expandoobject

I have a collection variable, whose elements are  `dynamic` type, that is returned from a database using Dapper extension.

The returned collection is this (variable name is `reporte`):

```
[0]: {{DapperRow, centroCosto = '(sin centro de costo)', Almuerzo = '20', Cena = '11', Desayuno = '2', Once = '3', servicios = '36', valorTotal = '106800,00'}}
[1]: {{DapperRow, centroCosto = 'ASESOR', Almuerzo = '18', Cena = '0', Desayuno = '0', Once = '0', servicios = '18', valorTotal = '55800,00'}}
[2]: {{DapperRow, centroCosto = 'AUXILIAR DE ASEO', Almuerzo = '6', Cena = '10', Desayuno = '5', Once = '6', servicios = '27', valorTotal = '70300,00'}}
[3]: {{DapperRow, centroCosto = 'DEMO', Almuerzo = '1437', Cena = '669', Desayuno = '57', Once = '71', servicios = '2234', valorTotal = '6880000,00'}}
[4]: {{DapperRow, centroCosto = 'INFORMÁTICA', Almuerzo = '4', Cena = '0', Desayuno = '0', Once = '0', servicios = '4', valorTotal = '12400,00'}}
[5]: {{DapperRow, centroCosto = 'PRACTICA DEMO', Almuerzo = '20', Cena = '0', Desayuno = '0', Once = '0', servicios = '20', valorTotal = '62000,00'}}
[6]: {{DapperRow, centroCosto = 'PRODEMO', Almuerzo = '81', Cena = '92', Desayuno = '2', Once = '3', servicios = '178', valorTotal = '563200,00'}}
```

From that list, I tell you that `centroCosto`, `servicios` and `valorTotal` fields are known and fixed, so, I can order that collection by any of those fields using `reporte.OrderBy(r => r.centroCosto)`, `reporte.OrderBy(r => r.servicios)` and `reporte.OrderBy(r => r.valorTotal)`.

Other fields are dynamic and I don't know their names in advance (that is why I used Dapper).

How can I order by those fields? For example, by `Almuerzo` field?

Comment: `IQueryable` is also has dynamic nature and it is possible to create OrderBy dynamically. post your SQL or better LINQ query which do the same.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv but how can I build the LINQ query? column names are not known at design time. They are retrieved from a database at runtime. For example, one of the retrieved column is called "Almuerzo" as the example in the question. For testing purposes, I have hardcoded one dynamic column. I tried with `reporte.OrderBy(r => r["Almuerzo"])` but it did not work.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv forget it. I have used `reporte.OrderBy(r => ((IDictionary<string, object>)r)[columnName]);` and it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the list object to idictionary to fetch the column name for sorting by orderby and then convert back to list. it is possible that you can sort the whole list and then you can use it with your dto to pass the list back to the client as:

For example, your list name is `ulist.` You can write it as:

```
ulist.OrderBy(r => ((IDictionary<string, object>)r)[columnName]);
```

Where `r` is an object of the list and `columnName` is the corresponding entity of that object.